# Does the word "Tractable" have an exact meaning in math?

Tags: probability, optimization

Suppose the joint probability associated with a statistical model is:

$$ p(x, Z, \theta)$$

Over here, $x$ are the random variables, $Z$ are the latent variables and $\theta$ are the parameters of the model that need to be estimated.

Although I haven't fully understood this point yet, but usually we want to remove the Latent Variables $Z$ from the estimation process since we are not interested in them and they further complicate the estimation process. So using the laws of probability, we can write:

$$L(\theta; X) = p(X | \theta) = \int p(X, Z | \theta) dZ$$

Given this information, I often hear the word "intractable" often mentioned alongside likelihood functions with Latent Variables, i.e. a Likelihood Function with Latent Variables is called an Intractable Likelihood ... and is considered much more difficult to work with compared to Likelihood Functions without Latent Variables.

A Likelihood function with Latent Variables is difficult to solve numerically (i.e. because multidimensional functions in general are difficult to optimize due to many local minima/maxima and saddle points).

But in general, this fact is true about any multidimensional function with or without latent variables.

To me, the obvious reason seems to be is that likelihood functions with latent variables involve marginalizing them out through integration ... and integration is generally a difficult process: with or without latent variables.

Given all this information - here is my question: Does the word "tractable" have an exact meaning in math? For example, if a given function satisfied properties a, b and c - this means that this function is tractable? And if one or more of these properties are not met, then the function is "not tractable"?

Or does "tractable" just refer to a general "high dimensional function that is difficult to optimize"? Using this logic, most real life functions are not tractable? Can anyone please offer insights into this?

Comment: "Intractable" generally refers to something that is possible in principle but not practical for problems with sizes of interest. E.g., brute force solution of the Traveling Salesman Problem is possible, but not practical for all but very small $n$. Global optimization of an arbitrary smooth function is similarly intractible since you can have arbitrarily many local extrema located in arbitrary positions, so global optimization at some point boils down to brute force searching.

Comment: Sometimes latent variables are actually helpful for maximum likelihood estimation. Check out EM algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

While the comment is correct, there can be another view of the term, especially with regard to probability distributions. Based on the use by my supervisor (in the field of Computer science), I use it similarly to the following quote:

> A distribution is tractable if any marginal probability induced by it can be computed in linear time.

from [On Using Sum-Product Networks for Multi-label Classification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8247024) (not my work).

Another source, coming from the probabilistic circuits area, relaxes this to polynomial time complexity and sets a proper **definition** that might satisfy even the most rigorous among us. See Definition 2 in Section 2.3 in the [Probabilistic Circuits: A Unifying Framework for Tractable Probabilistic Models](http://starai.cs.ucla.edu/papers/ProbCirc20.pdf).

Alternatively,

> Problems are said to be tractable if they can be solved in terms of a closed-form expression.

See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277953/what-does-a-tractable-distribution-mean) as a source of the explanations.